# fancybox gallery overlapped with Youtube player at the same page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

At this page,

http://nynj.ocef.org/2013concert_1.php

I have a fancybox gallery at the right, and a youtube iframe at the left. When I click at one of the thumnail photos in the gallery, a fancybox pops up to show the large photo, and I can navigate through the whole gallery. However, when the photo changes from current to the next, it's overlapped (or partly blocked) by the Youtube player at the right.

This happens to IE and Firefox, but in Chrome it's fine.

The fancybox gallery's z-index is 8040, and fancybox's overlay's z-index is 8010; I tried to set the youtube iframe's z-index to 1, but it didn't help.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with z-index, as they work only when position is applied in css to the element.

The problem is the transparency effect. transparency less then 1 makes an effect (kind of) lower z-index. so when the picture is changing and its transparent, the element is behind the iframe. changing z-index will do nothing with transparency. one suggestion is to make the following design change. maybe that might help, but i'm not sure.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="pictureGellary" style="position:relative; z-index:2"></div>
    <div id="iframe" style="position:relative; z-index:1"></div>
<div>
```

**Edit: This updated jquery.js code will solve the issue**

/*! fancyBox v2.1.5 fancyapps.com | fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license */
    (function(r,G,f,v){var J=f("html"),n=f(r),p=f(G),b=f.fancybox=function(){b.open.apply(this,arguments)},I=navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i),B=null,s=G.createTouch!==v,t=function(a){return a&&a.hasOwnProperty&&a instanceof f},q=function(a){return a&&"string"===f.type(a)},E=function(a){return q(a)&&0',image:'',iframe:'",error:'The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.

',closeBtn:'',next:'',prev:''},openEffect:"fade",openSpeed:250,openEasing:"swing",openOpacity:!0,
    openMethod:"zoomIn",closeEffect:"fade",closeSpeed:250,closeEasing:"swing",closeOpacity:!0,closeMethod:"zoomOut",nextEffect:"elastic",nextSpeed:250,nextEasing:"swing",nextMethod:"changeIn",prevEffect:"elastic",prevSpeed:250,prevEasing:"swing",prevMethod:"changeOut",helpers:{overlay:!0,title:!0},onCancel:f.noop,beforeLoad:f.noop,afterLoad:f.noop,beforeShow:f.noop,afterShow:f.noop,beforeChange:f.noop,beforeClose:f.noop,afterClose:f.noop},group:{},opts:{},previous:null,coming:null,current:null,isActive:!1,
    isOpen:!1,isOpened:!1,wrap:null,skin:null,outer:null,inner:null,player:{timer:null,isActive:!1},ajaxLoad:null,imgPreload:null,transitions:{},helpers:{},open:function(a,d){if(a&&(f.isPlainObject(d)||(d={}),!1!==b.close(!0)))return f.isArray(a)||(a=t(a)?f(a).get():[a]),f.each(a,function(e,c){var k={},g,h,j,m,l;"object"===f.type(c)&&(c.nodeType&&(c=f(c)),t(c)?(k={href:c.data("fancybox-href")||c.attr("href"),title:c.data("fancybox-title")||c.attr("title"),isDom:!0,element:c},f.metadata&&f.extend(!0,k,
    c.metadata())):k=c);g=d.href||k.href||(q(c)?c:null);h=d.title!==v?d.title:k.title||"";m=(j=d.content||k.content)?"html":d.type||k.type;!m&&k.isDom&&(m=c.data("fancybox-type"),m||(m=(m=c.prop("class").match(/fancybox\.(\w+)/))?m[1]:null));q(g)&&(m||(b.isImage(g)?m="image":b.isSWF(g)?m="swf":"#"===g.charAt(0)?m="inline":q(c)&&(m="html",j=c)),"ajax"===m&&(l=g.split(/\s+/,2),g=l.shift(),l=l.shift()));j||("inline"===m?g?j=f(q(g)?g.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/,""):g):k.isDom&&(j=c):"html"===m?j=g:!m&&(!g&&
    k.isDom)&&(m="inline",j=c));f.extend(k,{href:g,type:m,content:j,title:h,selector:l});a[e]=k}),b.opts=f.extend(!0,{},b.defaults,d),d.keys!==v&&(b.opts.keys=d.keys?f.extend({},b.defaults.keys,d.keys):!1),b.group=a,b._start(b.opts.index)},cancel:function(){var a=b.coming;a&&!1!==b.trigger("onCancel")&&(b.hideLoading(),b.ajaxLoad&&b.ajaxLoad.abort(),b.ajaxLoad=null,b.imgPreload&&(b.imgPreload.onload=b.imgPreload.onerror=null),a.wrap&&a.wrap.stop(!0,!0).trigger("onReset").remove(),b.coming=null,b.current||
    b._afterZoomOut(a))},close:function(a){b.cancel();!1!==b.trigger("beforeClose")&&(b.unbindEvents(),b.isActive&&(!b.isOpen||!0===a?(f(".fancybox-wrap").stop(!0).trigger("onReset").remove(),b._afterZoomOut()):(b.isOpen=b.isOpened=!1,b.isClosing=!0,f(".fancybox-item, .fancybox-nav").remove(),b.wrap.stop(!0,!0).removeClass("fancybox-opened"),b.transitionsb.current.closeMethod)))},play:function(a){var d=function(){clearTimeout(b.player.timer)},e=function(){d();b.current&&b.player.isActive&&(b.player.timer=
    setTimeout(b.next,b.current.playSpeed))},c=function(){d();p.unbind(".player");b.player.isActive=!1;b.trigger("onPlayEnd")};if(!0===a||!b.player.isActive&&!1!==a){if(b.current&&(b.current.loop||b.current.index=c.index?"next":"prev"],b.router=e||"jumpto",c.loop&&(0>a&&(a=c.group.length+a%c.group.length),a%=c.group.length),c.group[a]!==v&&(b.cancel(),b._start(a)))},reposition:function(a,d){var e=b.current,c=e?e.wrap:null,k;c&&(k=b._getPosition(d),a&&"scroll"===a.type?(delete k.position,c.stop(!0,!0).animate(k,200)):(c.css(k),e.pos=f.extend({},e.dim,k)))},update:function(a){var d=
    a&&a.type,e=!d||"orientationchange"===d;e&&(clearTimeout(B),B=null);b.isOpen&&!B&&(B=setTimeout(function(){var c=b.current;c&&!b.isClosing&&(b.wrap.removeClass("fancybox-tmp"),(e||"load"===d||"resize"===d&&c.autoResize)&&b._setDimension(),"scroll"===d&&c.canShrink||b.reposition(a),b.trigger("onUpdate"),B=null)},e&&!s?0:300))},toggle:function(a){b.isOpen&&(b.current.fitToView="boolean"===f.type(a)?a:!b.current.fitToView,s&&(b.wrap.removeAttr("style").addClass("fancybox-tmp"),b.trigger("onUpdate")),
    b.update())},hideLoading:function(){p.unbind(".loading");f("#fancybox-loading").remove()},showLoading:function(){var a,d;b.hideLoading();a=f('').click(b.cancel).appendTo("body");p.bind("keydown.loading",function(a){if(27===(a.which||a.keyCode))a.preventDefault(),b.cancel()});b.defaults.fixed||(d=b.getViewport(),a.css({position:"absolute",top:0.5*d.h+d.y,left:0.5*d.w+d.x}))},getViewport:function(){var a=b.current&&b.current.locked||!1,d={x:n.scrollLeft(),
    y:n.scrollTop()};a?(d.w=a[0].clientWidth,d.h=a[0].clientHeight):(d.w=s&&r.innerWidth?r.innerWidth:n.width(),d.h=s&&r.innerHeight?r.innerHeight:n.height());return d},unbindEvents:function(){b.wrap&&t(b.wrap)&&b.wrap.unbind(".fb");p.unbind(".fb");n.unbind(".fb")},bindEvents:function(){var a=b.current,d;a&&(n.bind("orientationchange.fb"+(s?"":" resize.fb")+(a.autoCenter&&!a.locked?" scroll.fb":""),b.update),(d=a.keys)&&p.bind("keydown.fb",function(e){var c=e.which||e.keyCode,k=e.target||e.srcElement;
    if(27===c&&b.coming)return!1;!e.ctrlKey&&(!e.altKey&&!e.shiftKey&&!e.metaKey&&(!k||!k.type&&!f(k).is("[contenteditable]")))&&f.each(d,function(d,k){if(1d,e.preventDefault(),!1;if(-1d,e.preventDefault(),!1})}),f.fn.mousewheel&&a.mouseWheel&&b.wrap.bind("mousewheel.fb",function(d,c,k,g){for(var h=f(d.target||null),j=!1;h.length&&!j&&!h.is(".fancybox-skin")&&!h.is(".fancybox-wrap");)j=h[0]&&!(h[0].style.overflow&&"hidden"===h[0].style.overflow)&&
    (h[0].clientWidth&&h[0].scrollWidth>h[0].clientWidth||h[0].clientHeight&&h[0].scrollHeight>h[0].clientHeight),h=f(h).parent();if(0!==c&&!j&&1g||0>k)b.next(0>g?"up":"right");d.preventDefault()}}))},trigger:function(a,d){var e,c=d||b.coming||b.current;if(c){f.isFunction(c[a])&&(e=c[a].apply(c,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)));if(!1===e)return!1;c.helpers&&f.each(c.helpers,function(d,e){if(e&&b.helpers[d]&&f.isFunction(b.helpers[d][a]))b.helpers[d][a](f.extend(!0,
    {},b.helpers[d].defaults,e),c)});p.trigger(a)}},isImage:function(a){return q(a)&&a.match(/(^data:image/.*,)|(.(jp(e|g|eg)|gif|png|bmp|webp|svg)((\?|#).*)?$)/i)},isSWF:function(a){return q(a)&&a.match(/.(swf)((\?|#).*)?$/i)},_start:function(a){var d={},e,c;a=l(a);e=b.group[a]||null;if(!e)return!1;d=f.extend(!0,{},b.opts,e);e=d.margin;c=d.padding;"number"===f.type(e)&&(d.margin=[e,e,e,e]);"number"===f.type(c)&&(d.padding=[c,c,c,c]);d.modal&&f.extend(!0,d,{closeBtn:!1,closeClick:!1,nextClick:!1,arrows:!1,
    mouseWheel:!1,keys:null,helpers:{overlay:{closeClick:!1}}});d.autoSize&&(d.autoWidth=d.autoHeight=!0);"auto"===d.width&&(d.autoWidth=!0);"auto"===d.height&&(d.autoHeight=!0);d.group=b.group;d.index=a;b.coming=d;if(!1===b.trigger("beforeLoad"))b.coming=null;else{c=d.type;e=d.href;if(!c)return b.coming=null,b.current&&b.router&&"jumpto"!==b.router?(b.current.index=a,bb.router):!1;b.isActive=!0;if("image"===c||"swf"===c)d.autoHeight=d.autoWidth=!1,d.scrolling="visible";"image"===c&&(d.aspectRatio=
    !0);"iframe"===c&&s&&(d.scrolling="scroll");d.wrap=f(d.tpl.wrap).addClass("fancybox-"+(s?"mobile":"desktop")+" fancybox-type-"+c+" fancybox-tmp "+d.wrapCSS).appendTo(d.parent||"body");f.extend(d,{skin:f(".fancybox-skin",d.wrap),outer:f(".fancybox-outer",d.wrap),inner:f(".fancybox-inner",d.wrap)});f.each(["Top","Right","Bottom","Left"],function(a,b){d.skin.css("padding"+b,w(d.padding[a]))});b.trigger("onReady");if("inline"===c||"html"===c){if(!d.content||!d.content.length)return b._error("content")}else if(!e)return b._error("href");
    "image"===c?b._loadImage():"ajax"===c?b._loadAjax():"iframe"===c?b._loadIframe():b._afterLoad()}},_error:function(a){f.extend(b.coming,{type:"html",autoWidth:!0,autoHeight:!0,minWidth:0,minHeight:0,scrolling:"no",hasError:a,content:b.coming.tpl.error});b._afterLoad()},_loadImage:function(){var a=b.imgPreload=new Image;a.onload=function(){this.onload=this.onerror=null;b.coming.width=this.width/b.opts.pixelRatio;b.coming.height=this.height/b.opts.pixelRatio;b._afterLoad()};a.onerror=function(){this.onload=
    this.onerror=null;b._error("image")};a.src=b.coming.href;!0!==a.complete&&b.showLoading()},_loadAjax:function(){var a=b.coming;b.showLoading();b.ajaxLoad=f.ajax(f.extend({},a.ajax,{url:a.href,error:function(a,e){b.coming&&"abort"!==e?b._error("ajax",a):b.hideLoading()},success:function(d,e){"success"===e&&(a.content=d,b._afterLoad())}}))},_loadIframe:function(){var a=b.coming,d=f(a.tpl.iframe.replace(/{rnd}/g,(new Date).getTime())).attr("scrolling",s?"auto":a.iframe.scrolling).attr("src",a.href);
    f(a.wrap).bind("onReset",function(){try{f(this).find("iframe").hide().attr("src","//about:blank").end().empty()}catch(a){}});a.iframe.preload&&(b.showLoading(),d.one("load",function(){f(this).data("ready",1);s||f(this).bind("load.fb",b.update);f(this).parents(".fancybox-wrap").width("100%").removeClass("fancybox-tmp").show();b._afterLoad()}));a.content=d.appendTo(a.inner);a.iframe.preload||b._afterLoad()},_preloadImages:function(){var a=b.group,d=b.current,e=a.length,c=d.preload?Math.min(d.preload,
    e-1):0,f,g;for(g=1;g<=c;g+=1)f=a[(d.index+g)%e],"image"===f.type&&f.href&&((new Image).src=f.href)},_afterLoad:function(){var a=b.coming,d=b.current,e,c,k,g,h;b.hideLoading();if(a&&!1!==b.isActive)if(!1===b.trigger("afterLoad",a,d))a.wrap.stop(!0).trigger("onReset").remove(),b.coming=null;else{d&&(b.trigger("beforeChange",d),d.wrap.stop(!0).removeClass("fancybox-opened").find(".fancybox-item, .fancybox-nav").remove());b.unbindEvents();e=a.content;c=a.type;k=a.scrolling;f.extend(b,{wrap:a.wrap,skin:a.skin,
    outer:a.outer,inner:a.inner,current:a,previous:d});g=a.href;switch(c){case "inline":case "ajax":case "html":a.selector?e=f("").html(e).find(a.selector):t(e)&&(e.data("fancybox-placeholder")||e.data("fancybox-placeholder",f('').insertAfter(e).hide()),e=e.show().detach(),a.wrap.bind("onReset",function(){f(this).find(e).length&&e.hide().replaceAll(e.data("fancybox-placeholder")).data("fancybox-placeholder",!1)}));break;case "image":e=a.tpl.image.replace("{href}",
    g);break;case "swf":e='',h="",f.each(a.swf,function(a,b){e+='';h+=" "+a+'="'+b+'"'}),e+='"}(!t(e)||!e.parent().is(a.inner))&&a.inner.append(e);b.trigger("beforeShow");a.inner.css("overflow","yes"===k?"scroll":
    "no"===k?"hidden":k);b._setDimension();b.reposition();b.isOpen=!1;b.coming=null;b.bindEvents();if(b.isOpened){if(d.prevMethod)b.transitionsd.prevMethod}else f(".fancybox-wrap").not(a.wrap).stop(!0).trigger("onReset").remove();b.transitionsb.isOpened?a.nextMethod:a.openMethod;b._preloadImages()}},_setDimension:function(){var a=b.getViewport(),d=0,e=!1,c=!1,e=b.wrap,k=b.skin,g=b.inner,h=b.current,c=h.width,j=h.height,m=h.minWidth,u=h.minHeight,n=h.maxWidth,p=h.maxHeight,s=h.scrolling,q=h.scrollOutside?
    h.scrollbarWidth:0,x=h.margin,y=l(x[1]+x[3]),r=l(x[0]+x[2]),v,z,t,C,A,F,B,D,H;e.add(k).add(g).width("auto").height("auto").removeClass("fancybox-tmp");x=l(k.outerWidth(!0)-k.width());v=l(k.outerHeight(!0)-k.height());z=y+x;t=r+v;C=E(c)?(a.w-z)*l(c)/100:c;A=E(j)?(a.h-t)*l(j)/100:j;if("iframe"===h.type){if(H=h.content,h.autoHeight&&1===H.data("ready"))try{H[0].contentWindow.document.location&&(g.width(C).height(9999),F=H.contents().find("body"),q&&F.css("overflow-x","hidden"),A=F.outerHeight(!0))}catch(G){}}else if(h.autoWidth||
    h.autoHeight)g.addClass("fancybox-tmp"),h.autoWidth||g.width(C),h.autoHeight||g.height(A),h.autoWidth&&(C=g.width()),h.autoHeight&&(A=g.height()),g.removeClass("fancybox-tmp");c=l(C);j=l(A);D=C/A;m=l(E(m)?l(m,"w")-z:m);n=l(E(n)?l(n,"w")-z:n);u=l(E(u)?l(u,"h")-t:u);p=l(E(p)?l(p,"h")-t:p);F=n;B=p;h.fitToView&&(n=Math.min(a.w-z,n),p=Math.min(a.h-t,p));z=a.w-y;r=a.h-r;h.aspectRatio?(c>n&&(c=n,j=l(c/D)),j>p&&(j=p,c=l(j*D)),cz||y>r)&&(c>m&&j>u)&&!(19n&&(c=n,j=l(c/D)),g.width(c).height(j),e.width(c+x),a=e.width(),y=e.height();else c=Math.max(m,Math.min(c,c-(a-z))),j=Math.max(u,Math.min(j,j-(y-r)));q&&("auto"===s&&jz||y>r)&&c>m&&j>u;c=h.aspectRatio?cu&&ja.closeClick?"close":"next")}),a.closeBtn&&f(a.tpl.closeBtn).appendTo(b.skin).bind("click.fb",function(a){a.preventDefault();b.close()}),a.arrows&&1f,b.inner[f](l("width"===
    f?c:c-g*e-h*e))},zoomIn:function(){var a=b.current,d=a.pos,e=a.openEffect,c="elastic"===e,k=f.extend({opacity:1},d);delete k.position;c?(d=this.getOrigPosition(),a.openOpacity&&(d.opacity=1)):"fade"===e&&(d.opacity=1);b.wrap.css(d).animate(k,{duration:"none"===e?0:a.openSpeed,easing:a.openEasing,step:c?this.step:null,complete:b._afterZoomIn})},zoomOut:function(){var a=b.current,d=a.closeEffect,e="elastic"===d,c={opacity:1};e&&(c=this.getOrigPosition(),a.closeOpacity&&(c.opacity=1));b.wrap.animate(c,
    {duration:"none"===d?0:a.closeSpeed,easing:a.closeEasing,step:e?this.step:null,complete:b._afterZoomOut})},changeIn:function(){var a=b.current,d=a.nextEffect,e=a.pos,c={opacity:1},f=b.direction,g;e.opacity=1;"elastic"===d&&(g="down"===f||"up"===f?"top":"left","down"===f||"right"===f?(e[g]=w(l(e[g])-200),c[g]="+=200px"):(e[g]=w(l(e[g])+200),c[g]="-=200px"));"none"===d?b._afterZoomIn():b.wrap.css(e).animate(c,{duration:a.nextSpeed,easing:a.nextEasing,complete:b._afterZoomIn})},changeOut:function(){var a=
    b.previous,d=a.prevEffect,e={opacity:0.1},c=b.direction;"elastic"===d&&(e["down"===c||"up"===c?"top":"left"]=("up"===c||"left"===c?"-":"+")+"=200px");a.wrap.animate(e,{duration:"none"===d?0:a.prevSpeed,easing:a.prevEasing,complete:function(){f(this).trigger("onReset").remove()}})}};b.helpers.overlay={defaults:{closeClick:!0,speedOut:200,showEarly:!0,css:{},locked:!s,fixed:!0},overlay:null,fixed:!1,el:f("html"),create:function(a){a=f.extend({},this.defaults,a);this.overlay&&this.close();this.overlay=
    f('').appendTo(b.coming?b.coming.parent:a.parent);this.fixed=!1;a.fixed&&b.defaults.fixed&&(this.overlay.addClass("fancybox-overlay-fixed"),this.fixed=!0)},open:function(a){var d=this;a=f.extend({},this.defaults,a);this.overlay?this.overlay.unbind(".overlay").width("auto").height("auto"):this.create(a);this.fixed||(n.bind("resize.overlay",f.proxy(this.update,this)),this.update());a.closeClick&&this.overlay.bind("click.overlay",function(a){if(f(a.target).hasClass("fancybox-overlay"))return b.isActive?
    b.close():d.close(),!1});this.overlay.css(a.css).show()},close:function(){var a,b;n.unbind("resize.overlay");this.el.hasClass("fancybox-lock")&&(f(".fancybox-margin").removeClass("fancybox-margin"),a=n.scrollTop(),b=n.scrollLeft(),this.el.removeClass("fancybox-lock"),n.scrollTop(a).scrollLeft(b));f(".fancybox-overlay").remove().hide();f.extend(this,{overlay:null,fixed:!1})},update:function(){var a="100%",b;this.overlay.width(a).height("100%");I?(b=Math.max(G.documentElement.offsetWidth,G.body.offsetWidth),
    p.width()>b&&(a=p.width())):p.width()>n.width()&&(a=p.width());this.overlay.width(a).height(p.height())},onReady:function(a,b){var e=this.overlay;f(".fancybox-overlay").stop(!0,!0);e||this.create(a);a.locked&&(this.fixed&&b.fixed)&&(e||(this.margin=p.height()>n.height()?f("html").css("margin-right").replace("px",""):!1),b.locked=this.overlay.append(b.wrap),b.fixed=!1);!0===a.showEarly&&this.beforeShow.apply(this,arguments)},beforeShow:function(a,b){var e,c;b.locked&&(!1!==this.margin&&(f("*").filter(function(){return"fixed"===
    f(this).css("position")&&!f(this).hasClass("fancybox-overlay")&&!f(this).hasClass("fancybox-wrap")}).addClass("fancybox-margin"),this.el.addClass("fancybox-margin")),e=n.scrollTop(),c=n.scrollLeft(),this.el.addClass("fancybox-lock"),n.scrollTop(e).scrollLeft(c));this.open(a)},onUpdate:function(){this.fixed||this.update()},afterClose:function(a){this.overlay&&!b.coming&&this.overlay.fadeOut(a.speedOut,f.proxy(this.close,this))}};b.helpers.title={defaults:{type:"float",position:"bottom"},beforeShow:function(a){var d=
    b.current,e=d.title,c=a.type;f.isFunction(e)&&(e=e.call(d.element,d));if(q(e)&&""!==f.trim(e)){d=f(''+e+"");switch(c){case "inside":c=b.skin;break;case "outside":c=b.wrap;break;case "over":c=b.inner;break;default:c=b.skin,d.appendTo("body"),I&&d.width(d.width()),d.wrapInner(''),b.current.margin[2]+=Math.abs(l(d.css("margin-bottom")))}d"top"===a.position?"prependTo":"appendTo"}}};f.fn.fancybox=function(a){var d,
    e=f(this),c=this.selector||"",k=function(g){var h=f(this).blur(),j=d,k,l;!g.ctrlKey&&(!g.altKey&&!g.shiftKey&&!g.metaKey)&&!h.is(".fancybox-wrap")&&(k=a.groupAttr||"data-fancybox-group",l=h.attr(k),l||(k="rel",l=h.get(0)[k]),l&&(""!==l&&"nofollow"!==l)&&(h=c.length?f(c):e,h=h.filter("["+k+'="'+l+'"]'),j=h.index(this)),a.index=j,!1!==b.open(h,a)&&g.preventDefault())};a=a||{};d=a.index||0;!c||!1===a.live?e.unbind("click.fb-start").bind("click.fb-start",k):p.undelegate(c,"click.fb-start").delegate(c+
    ":not('.fancybox-item, .fancybox-nav')","click.fb-start",k);this.filter("[data-fancybox-start=1]").trigger("click");return this};p.ready(function(){var a,d;f.scrollbarWidth===v&&(f.scrollbarWidth=function(){var a=f('').appendTo("body"),b=a.children(),b=b.innerWidth()-b.height(99).innerWidth();a.remove();return b});if(f.support.fixedPosition===v){a=f.support;d=f('').appendTo("body");var e=20===
    d[0].offsetTop||15===d[0].offsetTop;d.remove();a.fixedPosition=e}f.extend(b.defaults,{scrollbarWidth:f.scrollbarWidth(),fixed:f.support.fixedPosition,parent:f("body")});a=f(r).width();J.addClass("fancybox-lock-test");d=f(r).width();J.removeClass("fancybox-lock-test");f(".fancybox-margin{margin-right:"+(d-a)+"px;}").appendTo("head")})})(window,document,jQuery);

Also check ur site on opera and safari, the player is always on top in both. totally messed up.

Comment: Thank you, Bsienn! I tried to wrap the gallerary and the ifram as you suggested, but the problem remains.  Now I circumvent the problem by redesign the page and put youtube also in fancybox (http://nynj.ocef.org/2013concert.php). However, out of curiosity, I would still love to find out how to solve that problem (which is still available at http://nynj.ocef.org/2013concert_1.php).

Comment: Hi! i have updated the jquery.js of fancybox to make it work. replace the code edited above with ur jquery.js

Comment: The code you posted seems to be jquery.fancybox.pack.js v2.1.5, right?  I'm using it at my site now. Or did you make any change that deals with the problem?

Comment: yes i have made changes to code. i downloaded it from ur site yesterday. and the version is mentioned which is v2.1.5

Comment: strange, i checked it and it did work. that's why i posted it, well nvm what can i say. And i see u still have old fancybox js in ur source.